# Swift : what is the right way to split up a [String] resulting in a [[String]] with a given example?

Tags: arrays, slice

Starting with a large [String] and a given subarray size, what is the best way I could go about splitting up this array into smaller arrays? (The last array will be smaller than the given subarray size).

Concrete example:
Split up ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"] with max split size 4

The code would produce [["1","2","3","4"],["4","5","6","7"],["7","8","9"]]

Obviously I could do this a little more manually, but I feel like in swift something like map() or reduce() may do what I want really beautifully.

Comment: Why are 4 and 7 repeated?

Answer (score 0):

You can `map` over the indices into you array:

```swift
extension Array {
    func chunked(size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        let cnt = self.count
        return stride(from: 0, to: cnt, by: size).map {
            let end = Swift.min($0 + size, cnt)
            return Array(self[$0..<end])
        }
    }
}

["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"].chunked(size: 4)
// -> [["1", "2", "3", "4"], ["5", "6", "7", "8"], ["9"]]

["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"].chunked(size: 3)
// -> [["1", "2", "3"], ["4", "5", "6"], ["7", "8", "9"]]
```

Comment: Hello Sir, I tried in that way , but as per requirement it is not acceptable as shown result.I want to repeat 5 in both sub-arrays? I mean the ending number of previous sub-array should be starting number of next?

Comment: @ChetanPote Change `stride(from: 0, to: cnt, by: size)` to `stride(from: 0, to: cnt, by: size - 1)` gives `[["1","2","3","4"],["4","5","6","7"],["7","8","9"]]`.